# Can someone help me to solve this pycharm error xlrd

Tags: import-from-excel

Traceback (most recent call last): File "D:\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1\Python files\ReadExelFile.py", line 5, in wb= xlrd.open_workbook(x) File "D:\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1\venv\lib\site-packages\xlrd_*init*_.py", line 170, in open_workbook raise XLRDError(FILE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTIONS[file_format]+'; not supported') xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported

Comment: Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Learn to format your posts using markdown.

Answer (score 0):

upgrade your xlrd package

```
pip3 install --upgrade xlrd
```

or use this package to read xlsx files
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

```
pip3 install openpyxl
```